# why i cant have access to global variable in function void AddressBookUpdated(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working with an app in which I have to access the address book.  All the names are in an array.  The function I am using is:

```
#import "first.h"
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
@interface first ()
@property  (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *data;

@end

@implementation first
@synthesize data;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
void AddressBookUpdated(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context) {


  // NSMutableArray *data;
   //data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ABAddressBookRevert(addressBook);
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
    NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));


        NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@",
                              firstName, lastName];
        [data addObject:combined];//getting error "use of undeclared identifier 'date'"


}
```

I have declared data as you can see my code but still I am getting error "Use of undeclared 'data'"

Answer (score 1):

combined isn't a global variable - it is local to your `for` loop block.  If you want it to be available to other methods in your class then you should define it in your .h file, or even better declare a property in your .h file and then use self. to refer to it.

e.g.

in your .h file

```
@property  (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *data;
```

then in your .m file

```
void AddressBookUpdated(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context) {

    self.data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ABAddressBookRevert(addressBook);
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
    {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
        NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
        NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@",
                              firstName, lastName];
        [self.data addObject:combined];
        NSLog(@"data is %@",data);

        kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        //NSLog(@" name %@",combined);
    }
};
```

Comment: i have checked that but i cant access any global variable inside this function.

Comment: Which global variables are you trying to access?  Can you update your question so show their definition in your .h file?

Comment: as you can see in code that data is local here let say if i declare this in .h file & do the same this give the error data not declare

Comment: Then please show your declaration in the .h file and give details of the error - then perhaps I can help, but I recommend that you try using properties as per my answer